# ¿Como puedo cambiar el idioma de un campo de fecha y hora con Tempus Dominus Boostrap 4 en Angular?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7, datetimepicker

tengo un formulario dentro de un componente de angular y uno de los campos debe incluir tanto a la fecha como a la hora, para ello estoy utilizando el complemento de boostrap 4, el tempus dominus. Si se muestra correctamente, sin embargo cuando intento cambiar la zona a local me sigue mostrando el calendario en ingles, que es como viene por default. ¿Cómo podría conseguir que se muestre en español y el formato de fecha sea dia mes y año?. Este es mi código:

El código del html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest" NgTempusdominusBootstrap>
      <input
      [(ngModel)]="startDate"
      (ngModelChange)="update()"
      [options]="startOptions"
      NgTempusdominusBootstrapInput
      type="text" class="form-control"
      />
      <div class="input-group-append" NgTempusdominusBootstrapToggle>
          <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El codigo formulario.component.ts es:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formulario',
  templateUrl: './formulario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formulario.component.css']
})
export class FormularioComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default = $.extend({}, $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default, {
      icons: {
          time: 'fas fa-clock',
          date: 'fas fa-calendar-alt',
          up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
          down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
          previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
          next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
          today: 'fas fa-calendar-check-o',
          clear: 'fas fa-trash',
          close: 'fas fa-times'
      } });

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      local: 'es'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: si tienes momment basta con cambiarle el idioma a momment.js verifica en tu package.json

Comment: @JackNavaRow así es tengo moment pero como realizaría la configuración?